# Calculating body frame X vector's look direction in GEO (NED) frame from roll, pitch and yaw data, is this correct?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-earth-orbit, attitude, telemetry, frames

I have roll, pitch and yaw angle values for a LEO satellite. Satellite orbit frame and spacecraft body frame are defined as LVLH. The satellite position and velocity are given in ECI/GEI frame. I have to find where the satellite x unit vector looks in GEO frame.

For this, I am first rotating the unit vectors in LVLH according to the given roll, pitch, yaw angles (the attitude sequence is X-Y-Z: roll-pitch-yaw). Then convert the LVLH frame vectors to ECI(GEI) frame with Z-X-Z sequence and continue to the coordinate transformations:

ECI-->ECEF-->NED

LVLH to ECI: Z-X-Z sequence

```
sat_raan = raan*(math.pi/180)    #right ascencion of ascending node in radians
sat_inc = inc*(math.pi/180)      #satellite inclination in radians
sat_ap = ap*(math.pi/180)        #argument of perigee in radians

body_GEIx[:, i]=R_z(sat_raan) @ R_x(sat_inc) @ R_z(sat_ap) @ body_x[:, i]*GEIx[i]
body_GEIy[:, i]=R_z(sat_raan) @ R_x(sat_inc) @ R_z(sat_ap) @ body_y[:, i]*GEIy[i]
body_GEIz[:, i]=R_z(sat_raan) @ R_x(sat_inc) @ R_z(sat_ap) @ body_z[:, i]*GEIz[i]
```

ECI to ECEF: Only Z rotation: Theta: Greenwich sidereal time + Earth's rotation

```
body_ECEFx[:, i]=R_z(Theta) @ body_GEIx[:, i]
body_ECEFy[:, i]=R_z(Theta) @ body_GEIy[:, i]
body_ECEFz[:, i]=R_z(Theta) @ body_GEIz[:, i]
```

ECEF to NED: Z-Y rotation

```
rlon= -1*(math.pi/2+ (lon[i]* (math.pi/180))) #convert to radians
rlat= lat[i]*(math.pi/180) #convert to radians
    
body_NEDx[:, i]=R_z(rlon) @ R_y(rlat) @ body_ECEFx[:, i]
body_NEDy[:, i]=R_z(rlon) @ R_y(rlat) @ body_ECEFy[:, i]
body_NEDz[:, i]=R_z(rlon) @ R_y(rlat) @ body_ECEFz[:, i]
```

However, in North-East-Down(NED) frame, the body unit vectors do not look like they are orthogonal to each other, and there are some abrupt changes in look direction where I don't see any abrupt changes in roll, pitch and yaw. The satellite should be slewing for the interval that I'm interested in. However, I do not see any slewing.

I am so confused now: Should those vectors be orthogonal in the end? And am I doing the right thing by rotating the unit vectors in LVLH. Is it correct to multiply with the position vectors in ECI/GEI frame after transforming the body vectors to GEI?

[image: Roll, yaw, pitch angles for the satellite]

[image: S/C body frame vectors in GEO: black: X vector, Blue, Y vector, red: Z vector]

Comment: Great first question, *Welcome to Space!* I adjusted the title to better convey the nature of the question, please feel free to edit further.

Comment: thank you :)  @uhoh